# CMake creates x64 or Win32 directory outside its Build directory

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017

In CMake, I usually create a 'Build' directory at the root level of my source tree. I then CD into this directory, and do:

```
CMake .. -G "..."
```

In the past, all the CMake-related files would be created within this 'Build' directory. However, I now notice (after switching to new version of CMake, 3.7) that there is an 'x64' or 'Win32' file created in the root of the source tree when I build the project in Visual Studio.

How can I make it so that CMake creates these 'x64' or 'Win32' directories within the 'Build' directory and not in the parent directory, which is the root of the codebase?

Comment: Hm, it's been a while since I've built a CMake Project under windows useing MSVC. I don't remember that happening. Anyway, you've switched to a "new" cmake 3.7. I'm currently using 3.9 – why are you using a dated CMake?

Comment: That syntax looks wrong. Mandatory arguments almost always come *after* options. So it should be `cmake -G"Visual Studio 15 2017" ..` or just `cmake ..`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Visual Studio 2017? From the tags you have chosen, I think you are. There is actually a bug with Visual Studio 2017. You can read more details about it [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16458) since it has been first reported as a CMake bug.

In a nutshell, it seems to occur only when using "Rebuild" from the IDE. It results in a x64 (or Win32) folder being created in the root folder along with intermediate log files and such from ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK projects.

The issue has been closed by CMake 18 hours ago as it has been confirmed that this bug was fixed in Visual Studio 15.3.0.

Hope this helps.